# Stanford POS tagger doesn't work in servlet

Tags: servlets, stanford-nlp, tomcat8, pos-tagger

I am trying to use Stanford POS Tagger in Java servlet. I created Dynamic Web Page project in J2EE and included build path of jar files by following this tutorial.
http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/

If I create a separate java file, I am able to get POS Tagger working as shown below.

```
public static String tagger(String sample) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

 // Initialize the tagger
 MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");

 // The tagged string
 String tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);

 // Output the result
 return tagged;
 }

public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        System.out.println(tagger("This is a sample."));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which means POS tagger works in main method of simple Java class which I named Taggers.java. But when I try to instantiate the object of Tagger.java class in servlet, I can't get it working. The following code is a servlet in which I am trying to instantiate the object of Tagger.java.

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    try {
        out.println(Tagger.tagger("This is a sample sentence."));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run the above servlet on tomcat-8, it shows following exceptions.

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.exp.pkg.ExpServlet] in context with path [/webProj1] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
>       at com.exp.pkg.Tagger.tagger(Tagger.java:17)
>       at com.exp.pkg.ExpServlet.service(ExpServlet.java:34)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

After I set classpath=".;..;C:\Users\Faisal\workspace_EE\webProj1\tagger\english-left3words-distsim.ta‌​gger;C:\stanford-postagger-2015-01-29\stanford-postagger-2015-01-30\stanford-post‌​agger;C:\apache-tomcat-8\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\lib\servlet-api"

The stack trace is as follows:

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.exp.pkg.ExpServlet] in context with path [/webProj1] threw exception edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:769) at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.(MaxentTagger.java:297) at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.(MaxentTagger.java:262) at com.exp.pkg.Tagger.tagger(Tagger.java:17) at com.exp.pkg.ExpServlet.service(ExpServlet.java:34) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "tagger/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:463) at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:764) ... 27 more

Comment: It looks like the CoreNLP classes are not on your classpath. Is this the case?

Comment: classpath is explained on stanford's website http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml#api. Following the info on this link, I updated my classpath env. variable which looks like ".;..;C:\Users\Faisal\workspace_EE\webProj1\tagger\english-left3words-distsim.tagger;C:\stanford-postagger-2015-01-29\stanford-postagger-2015-01-30\stanford-postagger;C:\apache-tomcat-8\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\lib\servlet-api". This time error is little different such as 
"edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model"

Comment: Please post the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: I have just posted the entire stack trace after setting classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your classpath is correct.

From your updated post, it looks like you don't have the right model path on your classpath. You shouldn't add the `.tagger` file directly to your classpath; add the directory which contains the `tagger` folder. If your file setup looks like this:

```
C:\mystuff
    tagger\
        english-left3words-distsim.tagger
        english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger
```

then you should put the directory `C:\mystuff` on your classpath.

Comment: I have just posted my response below after updating the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to make sure your classpath is correct.
>
> From your updated post, it looks like you don't have the right model
>   path on your classpath. You shouldn't add the .tagger file directly to
>   your classpath; add the directory which contains the tagger folder. If
>   your file setup looks like this:
>
> C:\mystuff
>       tagger\
>           english-left3words-distsim.tagger
>           english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger then you should put the 
>   directory C:\mystuff on your classpath.

According to the instructions at the [link](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/) I have posted earlier, I created folder named tagger inside the project's root folder such as (C:\Users\Faisal\workspace_EE\webProj1\tagger), where I put the model "english-left3words-distsim.tagger" with it's .props file as directed on the tutorial link.
Now as you suggest to add only the folder to the classpath so my classpath becomes "C:\Users\Faisal\workspace_EE\webProj1\;C:\stanford-postagger-2015-01-29\stanford-postagger-2015-01-30\stanford-postagger;C:\apache-tomcat-8\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\lib\servlet-api"

This time, I got the following stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.exp.pkg.ExpServlet] in context with path [/webProj1] threw exception
edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:769)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:297)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:262)
    at com.exp.pkg.Tagger.tagger(Tagger.java:17)
    at com.exp.pkg.ExpServlet.service(ExpServlet.java:34)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "tagger/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:463)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:764)
    ... 27 more
```